# How to add click/tap function to a div tag in ionic view?

Tags: html, css, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I used fallowing code to when i click over `centerMarker` `div` tag it runs test function but it is not working.

**scss**

```
 page-posting {
      background: rgb(229, 227, 223);
      #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 2;
      }
      #centerMarker {
        width: 30px;
        height: 49px;
        display: block;
        content: ' ';
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 3;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin: -44px 0 0 -15px;
        background: url('../assets/img/start.svg');
        background-size: 30px 49px; 
        pointer-events: none; 
      }

      #map .gmnoprint img {
        width: 60px;
        height: 80px;
      }

      img {
        width: 60px;
        height: 80px;
      }

      .container-map {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0px;
          bottom: 0px;
          width: 100%;
          height: 96%;
          z-index: 1;
        }
      }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-content no-bounce>
  <ion-slides #slides (ionSlideWillChange)="onSlideChangeStart($event)" pager dir="rtl">
    <ion-slide>
      <div class="container-map">
        <div #map id="map"></div>
      </div>
<div id="centerMarker" (click)="test()"></div>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

**posting.ts**

```
test(){
console.log('it is work');
}
```

**console log**
I add click me  text to div to check it .
[image]

Comment: Hi, have you checked with the developer tools if the div is under the renderized map? Sometimes the map renders after the other elements, staying above, and you cant click the div under

Comment: @PailletJP thanks for your pay attention, I did some update in question. please check the console log. it seems you are right but how can I solve it?

Comment: Try adding a 

    z-index:99999; 

rule to your centerMarker element (you can try adding a lowest z-index to the map

Comment: @PailletJP l already added, in code `centerMarker` has value 3 for `z-index`, before that `centerMarker`  was not showing on `map div`.

Comment: I find it the problem is the `pointer-events: none; ` line of code.